# How to add related list in VF page

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I have created a Vf page for Standard object. In that VF page I need to add related list,like  in our default page. I am using PE for SalesforceKindly please tell any link for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Have you searched on google or force.com before ask here??*

[check this out](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm)`<apex:relatedList>`

sample

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:pageBlock>
    You're looking at some related lists for {!account.name}:
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" />

    <apex:relatedList list="Contacts">
        <apex:facet name="header">Titles can be overriden with facets</apex:facet>
    </apex:relatedList>

    <apex:relatedList list="Cases" title="Or you can keep the image, but change the text" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can I put custom buttons and checkboxes in a related list to process selected records using a wrapper class?